# ¿Cómo designar al sentimiento de "cabin fever"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

Este invierno está siendo un pelín más duro de lo normal aquí en Boston. Llevamos un par de semanas con temperaturas muy bajas (alrededor de unos 11 grados Farenheit, unos -6 grados centígrados) que hacen que no quieras salir de casa a menos que tengas que hacerlo. Pero aparte de ir a trabajar o a hacer la comprar, a veces tienes que salir... por salir de casa!

En inglés existe el término idiomático "[Cabin fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_fever)" que designa esa situación precisamente, como si estuvieses en una cabaña aislada en el monte, completamente rodeado de nieve y sin nada que hacer o donde ir. Este modismo se usa para expresar situaciones que van desde la claustrofobia hasta el aburrimiento.

Mi situación actual es el sentido más literal: Mañana (jueves), alerta por nieve, para el sábado se espera las nada envidiables temperaturas de -14˚C (la máxima) y -9˚C  el domingo, pero el modismo puede usarse en otras situaciones en el sentido figurado. Por ejemplo, si te vas de puente con los colegas a una casa rural y te das una maratón de pelis o de jugar videojuegos llega un momento que necesitas salir fuera de la casa a respirar y a hacer otra cosa.

Dado que esa situación claustrofóbica de "cabin fever" provoca, entre otras cosas, irritabilidad, a veces decimos que "nos subimos por las paredes", pero esta expresión se usa para designar [irritabilidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RucCTKo), más que la necesidad de salir fura de la casa y cambiar de aires y entorno o vencer el aburrimiento (y evitar [anquilosarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2kcyNcZ)).

Creo que nunca he oído en español la expresión "fiebre de la cabina" o "fiebre de la cabaña", que serían las traducciones más literales del término.

¿Hay un término o modismo en español que describa esa sensación de "cabin fever" que puede ser de irritabilidad, aburrimiento, hastío... por estar metido en casa durante muuuuucho tiempo sin prácticamente nada que hacer?

Comment: Como padre de niños pequeños sé lo importante que es que salgan a desfogar de vez en cuando a la calle. Si se pasan mucho tiempo en casa empiezan a comportarse mal, y entonces decimos que les da la "[pataleta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S7g9OGL)". Esa expresión la usamos también los adultos cuando llevamos mucho tiempo encerrados: decimos que estamos con la "pataleta". Pero claro, no sé hasta qué punto es común usar esa palabra con ese sentido, si es cosa de mi familia, de mi ciudad, o si es más conocida. Así que de momento dejo esto como comentario.

Comment: Charlie, para ver qué tanto se usa *pataleta*, ponla como respuesta, o pregunta específicamente.

Comment: Voté a cerrar la pregunta porque falta una frase que muestre cómo quieres usar la expresión.  Espero que agregues eso, por favor, es una pregunta interesante.

Comment: I enjoyed finding out that Spanish speakers climb up the wall(s) figuratively as well as English speakers under the same circumstances.

Comment: @walen - Me encanta el *tigre enjaulado*, creo que sí vale la pena ponerlo como respuesta, aunque no tengas fuente. // ¿Cómo se distingue entre regla y recomendación?

Comment: @diego - Yo de veras no puedo proponer una expresión sin saber cómo la quieres usar.

Comment: @aparente001, supongo que sería tan sencillo como "sufrir _cabin fever_". Si todavía [resides en el estado de NY](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2587/5481) supongo que acabáis de recibir (como nosotros en Masachussetts) un buen temporal de frío ártico (con su cancelación de colegios, transporte y otros servicios). Entre eso y que te defiendes bien en inglés, me sorprende que necesites un ejemplo aplicado para entender el uso de "cabin fever".

Comment: @diego - ¡Jajá, sí, me defiendo en inglés!  Y sí, lo que dices, del tiempo.  Hoy llevé a mi hijo a patinar para combatir el encierre.  Cuando estaba pequeño y no patinaba todavía, en mal tiempo lo llevaba al Walmart por ser la tienda más grande de la zona.  Al entrar vamos directo a la sección de bicicletas y él escoge algo de su tamaño.  Pasamos 3/4 de hora paseando por los pasillos amplios.  Funcionaba como una visita al parque.  Pero creo que tu hijo está a la edad de *push truck*.  Creo que también así funciona. // Aquí solo recibimos una pulgada de nieve pero sí la temperatura extrema.

Comment: @aparente001 cuando _era_ pequeño.

Comment: @fedorqui - Gracias.  Cuando era pequeño.

Comment: @Diego - Puedo imaginar *varios* usos del término "cabin fever", y es por eso que te pido una frase como ejemplo del uso que *tu* le quieres dar, y el contexto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En español sí se usa el termino "fiebre de cabaña" y también se encuentran las expresiones "fiebre de pradera" o "fiebre de montaña", que hacen referencia al estado emocional que se puede producir en las personas como consecuencia de un periodo de aislamiento, independientemente de la causa o circunstancias del mismo.

Aquí enlazo un articulo en que lo explica bastante bien: [Coronavirus: qué es la "fiebre de cabaña" que puede causar el confinamiento y cómo combatirla](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-52091584)

Comment: Jessica, bienvenida a Spanish Exchange. La respuesta la puedes complementar un poco más mostrando cómo se usan las expresiones mencionadas (enlaces referidos a *fiebre de pradera* y *fiebre de montaña*) y si sabes en que lugares se usan sería mejor (en mi país no recuerdo haber oído los términos)

Answer (score 10):

Nada más leer la pregunta me ha venido a la mente la frase «se me cae la casa encima». No conozco la expresión en inglés y sus matices pero cuando uno se siente agobiado en casa por diferentes motivos se usa esta expresión.

Las razones para sentir que la casa se le cae a uno encima pueden ser diversas y no siempre es por haber pasado mucho tiempo encerrado en ella así que quizá no sea exactamente lo mismo pero se parece bastante.

> [**caérsele** a alguien **la casa a cuestas,** o **encima**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7lsKMtR#Ai7PyKI)
>
> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Hacerse insoportable la permanencia en ella.

Comment: De hecho se parece tanto que creo que @Diego debería marcar esta respuesta como la aceptada.

Comment: La verdad es que sí. Pensaba que esta expresión solo tenía el significado de la segunda acepción "Sobrevenirle grave contrariedad o contratiempo.", pero el primero cuadra perfectamente.

Answer (score 6):

He encontrado una palabra muy curiosa en el diccionario:

> **[desapolillar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CSR2qUL)**
>
> 1. tr. Quitar la polilla a la ropa o a otra cosa.
> 2. prnl. coloq. Salir de casa cuando, por enfermedad u otra causa, ha transcurrido mucho tiempo sin salir de ella.

Curiosamente, no he encontrado en el CORDE ni en el CREA ni en la hemeroteca de la BNE ejemplos de esta segunda acepción. En el fichero general sí he encontrado una cédula que se refiere a la palabra con este significado (*1966 Moliner Dicc.*):

> Recibir el efecto agradable y beneficioso de salir de casa después de haber estado algún tiempo encerrado, por ejemplo estudiando, o salir de viaje o a diversiones después de haber estado algún tiempo recluido.

En todo caso, y dado que existe la acepción, podríamos hablar de *cabin fever* como de la "**necesidad de desapolillarse**".

Comment: En realidad "cabin fever" sería "apolillarse", que es la mala sensación de llevar metido en casa demasiado tiempo, pero como respuesta, 'desapolillar' es un descubrimiento genial.